# Android Dynamic Mqtt Topics not receiving Messages from the Broker

Tags: java, android, mqtt, android-networking

I'm using Eclipse Paho Library to connect with the mqtt Broker where there are multiple dynamics topics 
for e.g: new_user/# where I'm appending the UUID to the # for subscribing it.

Although the Library states that I'm Subscribing the topics successfully, the Mqtt Message Service doesn't receive any message from the broker at all. Please Help me out!

Here is the code:

```
public void message() {

        publishMessage(Topic1 + IEMINumber, Msg, false, 0, listener);
        mqttHelper = new MqttHelper(getApplicationContext());
        mqttHelper.deviceIEMI(IEMINumber);
        mqttHelper.setCallback(new MqttCallbackExtended() {

            @Override
            public void connectComplete(boolean b, String s) {}

            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {}

            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
                Log.w("Debug", mqttMessage.toString() + "\t" + topic);
            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Also the Helper class:

```
public class MqttHelper {

    public MqttAndroidClient mqttAndroidClient;

    final String serverUri = "tcp://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx";

    final String clientId = "ClientID";
    // final String subscriptionTopic = "example_topic";

    final String username = "your_username";
    final String password = "password";
    private String IemiNo;

    public MqttHelper(Context context) {
        mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(context, serverUri, clientId);
        mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(new MqttCallbackExtended() {
            @Override
            public void connectComplete(boolean b, String s) {
                Log.w("mqtt", s);
            }

            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
                Log.w("Mqtt_Connect", mqttMessage.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {

            }
        });
        connect();
    }

    public String deviceIEMI(String IEMINo) {
        IemiNo = IEMINo;
        return IEMINo;
    }

    public void setCallback(MqttCallbackExtended callback) {
        mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(callback);
    }


    private void connect() {
        MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
        mqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
        mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(false);
        mqttConnectOptions.setUserName(username);
        mqttConnectOptions.setPassword(password.toCharArray());

        try {

            mqttAndroidClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {

                    DisconnectedBufferOptions disconnectedBufferOptions = new DisconnectedBufferOptions();
                    disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferEnabled(true);
                    disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferSize(100);
                    disconnectedBufferOptions.setPersistBuffer(false);
                    disconnectedBufferOptions.setDeleteOldestMessages(false);
                    mqttAndroidClient.setBufferOpts(disconnectedBufferOptions);
                    subscribeToTopic();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Log.w("Mqtt", "Failed to connect to: " + serverUri + exception.toString());
                }
            });


        } catch (MqttException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void subscribeToTopic() {
        String[] subscriptionTopic = {"topic1/" + IemiNo, "topic2/" + IemiNo};

        try {
            mqttAndroidClient.subscribe(String.valueOf(subscriptionTopic), 0, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    Log.w("Mqtt", "Subscribed!");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Log.w("Mqtt", "Subscribed fail!");
                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException ex) {
            System.err.println("Exceptions subscribing");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please Let me know where I'm wrong or is this Library Issue!!

Comment: None of the 3 "answers" you have posted are actually real answers. Please pick one, edit it to include a description of what you changed and why and then delete the other 2.

Answer (score 1):

MainActivity.java

it was created to solve the underlying problems related to mqtt.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.net.Uri;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.FirebaseVision;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFace;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFaceDetector;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.face.FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

import org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttActionListener;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallbackExtended;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Created by AFSAR on 08/09/19.
 */

/**
 * This was a Dummy Activity created By AFSAR for TESTING PURPOSE on 08/09/19.
 **/
@SuppressWarnings("ALL")
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUESTS = 1;
    private static ImageView imageView1;
    private ImageView myImageView;
    private TextView myTextView;
    private Bitmap myBitmap;
    private MqttAndroidClient client;
    private PahoMqttClient pahoMqttClient;
    private MqttAndroidClient mqttAndroidClient;
    private String IEMINumber;
    private String utopic;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
    private String mCurrentLocation, cityName, pubresult, msg;
    private Context context;
    private IMqttActionListener listener;
    private MqttHelper mqttHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //setTitle("Firebase Barcode Scanner");
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            getRuntimePermissions();
        }
        myTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        myImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView1 = findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        pahoMqttClient = new PahoMqttClient();
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        Button publish = findViewById(R.id.publish);
        Button subscribe = findViewById(R.id.subscribe);
        Button barcode = findViewById(R.id.barcode);
        Button imageu = findViewById(R.id.imageu);
        Button face = findViewById(R.id.facerecog);
        Button bulktest = findViewById(R.id.bulktest);

        IEMINumber = MqttConstant.getIMEI(MainActivity.this);
        client = pahoMqttClient.getMqttClient(MainActivity.this, Constants.MQTT_BROKER_URL, Constants.CLIENT_ID, IEMINumber);
        mqttAndroidClient = pahoMqttClient.getMqttClient(getApplicationContext(), Constants.MQTT_BROKER_URL, Constants.CLIENT_ID, IEMINumber);
        mqttHelper = new MqttHelper(getApplicationContext());
        mqttHelper.deviceIEMI(IEMINumber);

        publish.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                            if (location != null) {
                                // Logic to handle location object
                                mCurrentLocation = location.getLatitude() + "\t" + location.getLongitude();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mCurrentLocation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                                List<Address> addresses;
                                try {
                                    addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                                    if (addresses != null) {
                                        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                                            cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, cityName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
            //getDeviceIMEI();
            message();
        });

        subscribe.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            publishMsg(pubresult);
            subscribeTopic();
        });

        barcode.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainTesting.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });

        imageu.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BulkImage.class);
            i.putExtra("userid", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            i.putExtra("productscan", "www.google.com");
            i.putExtra("productURL", "www.google.com");
            startActivity(i);
        });

        face.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result2Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("userid", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            i.putExtra("productscan", "www.google.com");
            i.putExtra("productURL", "www.google.com");
            i.putExtra("product-url", "www.google.com");
            i.putExtra("RawResult", "www.google.com");
            startActivity(i);
        });

        bulktest.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraHidden.class);
            startActivity(j);
            finish();
        });

        msg = "DEMO FOR Publish" + "\t" + "1";
        String uniqueid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String s1 = uniqueid.substring(0, 4);
        Log.e("s1", s1);
    }

    public void message() {
        publishMessage(MqttConstant.FIRST_IMAGE + IEMINumber, msg, false, 0, listener);
        mqttHelper.setCallback(new MqttCallbackExtended() {
            @Override
            public void connectComplete(boolean b, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
                Log.w("M-Debug", mqttMessage.toString() + "\n" + topic);
                utopic = topic;
                if (utopic.contains(IEMINumber)) {
                    Log.e("UNIQUE--ID--MATCH", "YIPPEEE");
                } else {
                    Log.e("OOPSS", "SEDD");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {

            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint({"HardwareIds", "MissingPermission"})
    public String getDeviceIMEI() {
        String deviceUniqueIdentifier = null;
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (null != tm) {
            deviceUniqueIdentifier = tm.getDeviceId();
        }
        if (null == deviceUniqueIdentifier || 0 == deviceUniqueIdentifier.length()) {
            deviceUniqueIdentifier = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        }
        String device_UUID = MqttConstant.getDeviceUniqueID(MainActivity.this);
        Log.e("device_unique", device_UUID);
        Log.w("iemi_device", deviceUniqueIdentifier);
        return deviceUniqueIdentifier;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case WRITE_STORAGE:
                    checkPermission(requestCode);
                case CAMERA:
                    checkPermission(requestCode);
                    break;
                case SELECT_PHOTO:
                    Uri dataUri = data.getData();
                    String path = MyHelper.getPath(this, dataUri);
                    if (path == null) {
                        myBitmap = MyHelper.resizePhoto(photoFile, this, dataUri, myImageView);
                    } else {
                        myBitmap = MyHelper.resizePhoto(photoFile, path, myImageView);
                    }
                    if (myBitmap != null) {
                        myTextView.setText(null);
                        myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                        runFaceDetector(myBitmap);
                        changeBitmapContrastBrightness(myBitmap, 1, 70);
                    }
                    break;
                case TAKE_PHOTO:
                    myBitmap = MyHelper.resizePhoto(photoFile, photoFile.getPath(), myImageView);
                    if (myBitmap != null) {
                        myTextView.setText(null);
                        myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                        runFaceDetector(myBitmap);
                        changeBitmapContrastBrightness(myBitmap, 1, 70);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void changeBitmapContrastBrightness(Bitmap bmp, float contrast, float brightness) {
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[]
                {
                        contrast, 0, 0, 0, brightness,
                        0, contrast, 0, 0, brightness,
                        0, 0, contrast, 0, brightness,
                        0, 0, 0, 1, 0
                });

        Bitmap ret = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(ret);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);
        //Log.e("return-of-contrast", ret.toString());
        contrastingImage(ret);
    }

    private static void contrastingImage(Bitmap bmm) {
        //Log.e("bmm", bmm.toString());
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(bmm);
    }

    private void runFaceDetector(Bitmap bitmap) {
        FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions options = new FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                //.setModeType(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.FAST_MODE)
                .setClassificationMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
                .setLandmarkMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_LANDMARKS)
                .setMinFaceSize(0.1f)
                //  .setTrackingEnabled(false)
                .build();

        FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(myBitmap);
        FirebaseVisionFaceDetector detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionFaceDetector(options);
        detector.detectInImage(image).addOnSuccessListener(faces -> myTextView.setText(runFaceRecog(faces)))
                .addOnFailureListener(exception -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Exception",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
    }

    public String runFaceRecog(List<FirebaseVisionFace> faces) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        float smilingProbability = 0;
        float rightEyeOpenProbability = 0;
        float leftEyeOpenProbability = 0;
        int id = 1;

        for (FirebaseVisionFace face : faces) {
            if (face.getSmilingProbability() != FirebaseVisionFace.UNCOMPUTED_PROBABILITY) {
                smilingProbability = face.getSmilingProbability();
            }
            if (face.getRightEyeOpenProbability() != FirebaseVisionFace.UNCOMPUTED_PROBABILITY) {
                rightEyeOpenProbability = face.getRightEyeOpenProbability();
            }
            if (face.getLeftEyeOpenProbability() != FirebaseVisionFace.UNCOMPUTED_PROBABILITY) {
                leftEyeOpenProbability = face.getLeftEyeOpenProbability();
            }

            result.append("Smile: ");
            if (smilingProbability > 0.5) {
                result.append("Yes \nProbability: ").append(smilingProbability);
            } else {
                result.append("No");
            }
            result.append("\n\nRight eye: ");
            if (rightEyeOpenProbability > 0.5) {
                result.append("Open \nProbability: ").append(rightEyeOpenProbability);
            } else {
                result.append("Close");
            }
            result.append("\n\nLeft eye: ");
            if (leftEyeOpenProbability > 0.5) {
                result.append("Open \nProbability: ").append(leftEyeOpenProbability);
            } else {
                result.append("Close");
            }

            result.append("\n\nFaceID: ").append(id++);
            result.append("\n\n");
        }

        // passing the result to private object and then passed to another method as constructor object...
        pubresult = result.toString();
        publishMsg(pubresult);
        //Log.e("DATA", faceresult);
        return result.toString();

    }

    public void publishMsg(String pubresult) {
        String uniquemessage = "MQTT COMPLEXITIES ";
        try {
            if (pubresult != null) {
                //pahoMqttClient.publishMessage(client, pubresult, 0, Constants.PRODUCT_CODE); MqttConstant.getIEMI(MainActivity.this)
                pahoMqttClient.publishMessage(client, pubresult, 1, Constants.PUBLISH_TOPIC + IEMINumber);
            } else {
                //pahoMqttClient.publishMessage(client, uniquemessage, 0, MqttConstant.NEW_USER_DETAIL);
                pahoMqttClient.publishMessage(client, uniquemessage, 0, "product_url/" + IEMINumber);
            }

        } catch (MqttException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    protected void publishMessage(String topic, String message, boolean isRetained, int qos, IMqttActionListener listener) {

        MqttMessage mqttMessage = new MqttMessage(message.getBytes());
        Log.w("mqtt_message", mqttMessage.toString());
        mqttMessage.setRetained(isRetained);
        mqttMessage.setQos(qos);

        try {
            mqttAndroidClient.publish(topic, mqttMessage, context, listener);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void subscribeTopic() {
        try {
            try {
                mqttAndroidClient.subscribe("product_scanned/#", 1);
                mqttAndroidClient.subscribe("first_image/#", 1);
                mqttAndroidClient.subscribe("error_msg/#", 1);
                mqttAndroidClient.subscribe("old_user/#", 1);
                mqttAndroidClient.subscribe("new_user_details/#", 1);
                mqttAndroidClient.subscribe("new_user/#", 1);
                mqttAndroidClient.subscribe("product_code/#", 1);
                mqttAndroidClient.subscribe("product_url/#", 1);
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String[] getRequiredPermissions() {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
            String[] ps = info.requestedPermissions;
            if (ps != null && ps.length > 0) {
                return ps;
            } else {
                return new String[0];
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new String[0];
        }
    }

    private boolean allPermissionsGranted() {
        for (String permission : getRequiredPermissions()) {
            if (!isPermissionGranted(this, permission)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void getRuntimePermissions() {
        List<String> allNeededPermissions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String permission : getRequiredPermissions()) {
            if (!isPermissionGranted(this, permission)) {
                allNeededPermissions.add(permission);
            }
        }

        if (!allNeededPermissions.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, allNeededPermissions.toArray(new String[0]), PERMISSION_REQUESTS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NotNull String[] permissions, @NotNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Permission granted!");
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            // onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    private static boolean isPermissionGranted(Context context, String permission) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Permission granted: " + permission);
            return true;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Permission NOT granted: " + permission);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This still needs an actual explanation of what you changed and why. Without copy/pasting this and all the code in the question into files and diffing them there is no way to spot what you changed.